# Enabling YouTube for Google Apps for Domain, in the UK or Switzerland

Tags: google-workspace, youtube

When I click sign in in YouTube I'm shown this message:

> YouTube has not been enabled by the administrator of the domain
>   @example.com.
>
> You can sign into another account to use YouTube.
>
> If you are the Google Apps administrator, please read these articles
>   to learn more about controlling user access to Google Apps services
>   and turning services on/off for certain users.

Since I am the administrator I tried enabling it but YouTube is nowhere to be found in the list of services of my domain. Any ideas how to enable it?

I am located in the UK, but my default country is set to Switzerland, where I used to live. I don't see how to change it though.

Comment: my panel doesnt have youtube option, what can i do now?

Comment: the setting may have something to do with the country setting. I too live in Switzerland and do NOT see the youtube service in the Google Apps dashboard (under Orgs & Users / Services) Anyone else have an idea? I've been looking for a way to do this for months.

Comment: I live in Austria & Denmark; YouTube is also missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I see YouTube listed in the dashboard, under "Organization & users" > "Services":
`https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/my.domain/Organization#Organization/subtab=services`

This is [described in the help center](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82691&topic=1227580&ctx=topic).

Comment: I can't see anything in there :